# How can I add dynamic columns on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `jquery datatables` to display data.

```
 <table  class="report-tbl table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="report-tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><span contenteditable="">Side A</span></th>
                    <th><span contenteditable="">Sode B</span></th>
                    <th><span contenteditable="">Side C</span></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="rowcontainer">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

> I want to happen is that when I click a button **data-table will add a column 'Side D'**.

Do you have any idea on how I can do this. Cause base on what I see in google. `jQuery data-tables` do not support yet Add/Remove Dynamic columns.

Thank You,

Comment: have you considered putting it in from the start and toggling the display?

Comment: it is only a sample column i will add. but there is a possibility that  will more than 2 columns.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any jquery library then try this

```
$($("thead").find("tr")[0]).append("<th <span contenteditable="">Side D</span></th>");
```

Comment: it only appends the column on the table but doesn't add it on data-tables :(